# Running .exe file continuously with windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to run an exe file and If this exe shutdown, windows service must start again this exe by checking whether closed or not with time interval.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        string filename = "C:\\a.exe"; 
        Process.Start(filename);
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Get Reference to the current Process
    Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    if (IsProcessOpen("name of application.exe") == false)
    {
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application not open!");
        //System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
        // Check how many total processes have the same name as the current one
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
        {
            // If ther is more than one, than it is already running.
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.");
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```